# Can grep or sed show only words that match multiple search patterns in a line?

Tags: perl, awk, sed, grep

I am wondering, if one can print the matched strings as it is in each line... using grep or sed?

## TestCase1: File1 contains below text

```
The Sun
Thunder The Rain They say
They say The dance
```

If I use this command:

```
egrep -o 'The|They' File1
```

The output I get is:

```
The
The
They
They
The
```

But, my expected output should be as below:

```
The
The They
They The
```

I am aware that, In grep the option -o, --only-matching prints only the matched non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

Edit: Please also suggest, if one wants to have a filter with exact word match with multiple match strings

```
 i.e. <The> and <They> exact word match? Space separated words simply.
```

## TestCase2: File2 contains below text

```
The Sun
Thunder The Rain They say
They say The dance
They're dancing with them in the dorm
The sun is shining the east and they scream.
```

Output is:

```
The
The They
They the
the
The the they
```

How to approach this?

Comment: You could ask it to add line-numbers, then use those to reassemble it.

Comment: @EdMorton, I am concerned about the exact word match. That's it. Hence, Them and They're shall also be deleted post filtering.

Comment: Because, I think, if an exact word match is specified in the filter, that query can be solved. i.e <them> <they're> both shall be deleted as both does not match the strong <the> or <they>. So, I would thankful if you could suggest the exact word match thing?

Comment: @EdMorton: Sure. Let me edit all the test cases and explain the question better. Thanks for such a wonderful advice.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks for such a wonderful ideas and feedback. Your points are pretty valid and one would certainly want such modifications later in the script as far as word boundary and quoted words are concerned. But presently, the concern is about a simple match with space separated. Also, It would be so good of you, if you can provide all such modification in detail with various test cases as you have suggested. It shall turn a nice article for readers like me.

Comment: @EdMorton: I understand. I really appreciate your help and all the suggestion so far. The entire discussions and various approach to this problems have been already a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best do it with Perl:

```
~$ perl -nE 'say /They? /g' File1
The
The They
They The
```

**EDIT** : Add new conditions. The regex still matches all but the lowercase `the`. Adding the `i` flag makes the match case-insensitive and matches all your test strings.

```
$ perl -nE 'say /They? /ig' File1
The
The They
They The
the
The the they
```

There is a little bit of a trick here: the match also picks up the space after the `?` and prints it in the output. E.g. the first line of output is realy: "The_\n" - where "_" = space character. This may or may not be acceptable. One way to remove the spaces and reassemble the string would be:

```
$ perl -nE 'say join " ", map {substr $_,0,-1} /They? /ig' File1
```

As to your question about matching full words <The> and <They>, as you put it, the `?` in `They?` indicates that the 'y' is optional. I.e. matches 0 or 1 times. Therefore the pattern is considering 'The' and 'They' as full words, one or the other, followed by a space. You could rewrite the pattern as:

```
$ perl -nE 'say /(?:They|The) /ig' File1
```

And effect the same output.

Now that you are considering lowercase `the` you may run into more edge case "gotchas" like words that end in "the". "loathe" and "tythe" come to mind.

```
$ echo "I'm loathe to cringe and tythe socks" >> File1
$ perl -nE 'say /They? /ig' File1
The
The They
They The
the
The the they
the the  <--- not wanted!
```

You can then add the `\b` test in to match on word boundaries (as in zdim's answer):

```
$ perl -nE 'say /\bThey? /ig' File1
The
The They
They The
the
The the they
              <-- But you get this empty line where no match occurs
```

So to refine further, you could only print if the line matches. Like this:

```
$ perl -nE 'say /\bThey? /ig if /\bThey? /i' File1
The
The They
They The
the
The the they
```

Then, I'm sure, you can find more edge cases that will blow it all up and force further refinement.

Comment: Perl magic again.. What does // do? Where can I find the reference?

Comment: The `//` defines a regex in Perl. Read more [here](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: @cbmckay Can you please suggest about the exact match words condition? considering <The> and <They> separately. And something like The|They kind of stuff different words.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk for `FPAT`:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='\\<[Tt]hey?\\>' '{$1=$1}1' file
The
The They
They The
They the
The the they
```

Note that that can't NOT identify `They` when it appears in `They're`. If that's really an issue and you want to look for space-separated complete strings then this might be what you want:

```
$ awk '{c=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i ~ /^[Tt]hey?$/) printf "%s%s", (c++?OFS:""), $i; print ""}' file
The
The They
They The
the
The the they
```

If not, let us know.

The above was run against this iteration of the OPs posted sample input:

```
$ cat file
The Sun
Thunder The Rain They say
They say The dance
They're dancing with them in the dorm
The sun is shining the east and they scream.
```

Comment: Could you please do let me know which version of awk you are using, as I am using GNU Awk 3.1.7 and not finding this option "FPAT". Will be grateful to you sir.

Comment: This will print any word that contains `The`. Try `echo 'Them Then Matches?' | awk -v FPAT='They?' '{$1=$1}1'`

Comment: Try `echo 'Them Then daTheu?' | awk -v FPAT='They?' '{$1=$1}1'`

Comment: I think you want `awk -v FPAT='\\<They?\\>' '{$1=$1}1'` with word boundaries.

Comment: @dawg I posted the answer before the OP clarified their requirements for partial matches. Yes, given their now state requirements you would want some kind of boundaries as well as case insensitivity but word boundaries wouldn't eliminate matching `They` in `They're` as the OP wants.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 your awk version is about 5 years and several releases behind. `FPAT` has been in gawk since 4.0 which came out a few years ago. Get an updated gawk as you're missing a TON of extremely useful functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Things are not fully specified so here are a couple of possibilities

- To catch all words starting with `The`, and print them with a space in between

  ```
  perl -wnE'say join " ", /\bThe\w*/g' file
  ```

  where `\b` is a word-boundary, a zero-width [anchor](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html#ANCHORS), and `\w` is a word character. Using `\S` (a non-space character) is yet more permissive.
- For only `The` or `They` can instead use

  ```
  perl -wnE'say join " ", /\bThey?\b/g' file
  ```

  where `y?` makes `y` optional.

To allow `the` as well use `[tT]` instead of `T` in the pattern, or `/i` for either case for all chars.

---

It's been clarified in coments that punctuation after `The|They` isn't allowed, and that low case `t` is. Then we need to constrain the match by space, not word boundary, and use `[tT]` as mentioned

```
perl -wnE'say join " ", /\b([Tt]hey?)\s/g'  file
```

Now the capturing parenthesis `()` are needed since `\s` does consume, unlike `\b` before.

This prints the desired output with the provided input.

Comment: Suggest `perl -wnE 'say join " ",/\bThey?\b/g'`

Comment: @dawg  Right, much better. Plus I needed it at another place as well. Thank you!

Comment: @Linguist I updated (at the end) to your comments and edit. I am still not sure that I got your requirements, please clarify if not.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v p="They?" '$0~p{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~p) printf "%s",$i OFS; print ""}' file

The
The They
They The
```

Comment: This matches anything that contains `The` including `daThehu`

Answer (score 1):

try one more awk:

```
awk '{while(match($0,/The|They/)){string=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);VAL=VAL?VAL OFS string:string;$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1);};print VAL;VAL=""}'   Input_file
```

NON-ONE line form of solution as follows too.

```
awk '{
        while(match($0,/The|They/)){
                                        string=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);
                                        VAL=VAL?VAL OFS string:string;
                                        $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH+1);
                                   };
        print VAL;
        VAL=""
     }
    '   Input_file
```

Will add the explanation shortly for same.

Comment: Matches anything containing `The` like *Therefor* and *daTheum* and *Theater*

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 : If a line does not contain any single matched words, then it do deletes all the unmatched string and hence empty line. How to avoid the empty line print? It would be good if empty line is not printed at all.